# Proving divergence by contradiction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $ a_k $ be some sequence with $ a_k > 0 $ for all $k$. Let

$$u_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \left( a_k + \frac{1}{a_k}\right)$$

I aim to show that the sequence $u_n$ diverges as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

To do this I use contradiction. Let us assume that it converges. Then the sequence of summands, $a_k + \frac{1}{a_k}$, must tend to $0$. Since $a_k > 0$, we would require $a_k$ and $\frac{1}{a_k}$ to both tend to $0$. These cannot both happen - for example if $|a_n| < \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon$ and $n \geq N$, then $\frac{1}{|a_n|} > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ and vice versa. So our original assumption must have been false, and so the sequence $u_n$ diverges.

Is it okay to use the fact that the sequence of summands must tend to $0$ here? Is this proof correct? Can this be proven directly?

Comment: Note that $x+\frac 1x≥2$, for $x>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is fine.
The direct proof requires showing that $ \forall M \in \Bbb{R},\ \exists N \in \Bbb{N}:n\ge N \implies a_n\ge M$. The inequality provided in the comments, which is a simple consequence of AM-GM, tells that $u_n\ge 2n \ge M, \forall M\in \Bbb{R}$, if n is sufficiently large, by Archimedean property. Thus we are done.